# number of lines with number of words less than 5

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Using pyspark,
I would like to find number of lines that has number of words < 5

I wrote this code but I couldn't figure out what is wrong with it

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row


spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://master:7077").appName('test').config(conf=SparkConf()).getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.text('text.txt')
rdd = df.rdd
print(df.count())
rdd1=rdd.filter(lambda line: len((line.split(" "))<5)).collect()
print(rdd1.count())

This is the a small part of the Error
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-48-27233afa0b82> in <module>()
          9 rdd = df.rdd
         10 print(df.count())
    ---> 11 rdd1=rdd.filter(lambda line: len((line.split(" "))<5)).collect()
         12 print(rdd1.count())
         13 
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 144.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 144.0 (TID 144, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ff/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1497, in __getattr__
    idx = self.__fields__.index(item)
ValueError: 'split' is not in list
```

Comment: How do you know that there is a problem with your code? Do you get a specific error message? Do you get the wrong number of lines? Does it make your computer explode?

Comment: I added the first part of the error. I cannot add the whole error because it is  very long.

Comment: Try to use rdd1=rdd.filter(lambda line: len((line.text.split(" "))<5)).collect()

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was that I was trying to split a list.
This is the new line

```
rdd=rdd.filter(lambda line: len(line[0].split(" "))<5).collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some parentheses in the wrong place in this expression:

```
rdd1=rdd.filter(lambda line: len((line.split(" "))<5)).collect()
```

The way you have it, you're doing this:

```
len(... < 5)
```

Instead of this:

```
len(...) < 5
```

Comment: I tried this one now rdd1=rdd.filter(lambda line: len(line.split(" "))<5).collect()
but it didn't work as well

Comment: "It didn't work" isn't much of a description.  We'll need more details if you want us to help.

Comment: The input box here does not allow me to put the whole error but I added a bit more