# Error converting RDD row to a dataframe with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I wrote a function that I want to apply to a dataframe, but first I have to convert the dataframe to a RDD to map. Then I print so I can see the result:

```
x = exploded.rdd.map(lambda x: add_final_score(x.toDF()))
print(x.take(2))
```

The function add_final_score takes a dataframe, which is why I have to convert x back to a DF before I pass it through. However, it give me this error that toDF is not in the list:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-491-11e7b77ecf3f> in <module>()
     42 #                      StructField('segmentName', StringType(), True)])
     43 # x = exploded.rdd.map(lambda y: y.toDf())
---> 44 print(x.take(2))

~/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py in take(self, num)
   1356 
   1357             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1358             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   1359 
   1360             items += res

~/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
    999         # SparkContext#runJob.
   1000         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
-> 1001         port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
   1002         return list(_load_from_socket(port, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
   1003 

~/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1158         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1159         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1160             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1161 
   1162         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    318                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    319                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 320                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    321             else:
    322                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 78.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 78.0 (TID 78, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lisa/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1556, in _getattr_
    idx = self.__fields__.index(item)
ValueError: 'toDF' is not in list
```

What does it mean? What list?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667879/number-of-lines-with-number-of-words-less-than-5/40680360

Comment: if we can see `add_final_score` function and if you explain what are your trying to achieve then we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

"toDF" workes on a DataFrame like you can see here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=todf#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toDF

In your code, I guess "exploded" is a df so after you use ".rdd"  on it, it becomes an rdd. Then when you use "map" you get back an rdd again.

You can't apply "toDF" on the rdd rows. If you want to turn the rdd back into a DataFrame you need to use something like (Depending on you spark version): https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=createdataframe#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame

Also, you can't apply a function on a DataFrame using "map" because an rdd can't hold DataFrames it has rows